# Only one frame renders, and without image in the end

Tags: rendering

My final render doesn't appear at all on my laptop!

The render preview view shows the objects, but when I finally render it I can't see any images or video, and it only renders one frame.

I tried to redo the render but it doesn't get fixed at all
1- the image is rendering
[image]
2- blender stop rendering !
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Objects not Appearing:**
Make sure your objects are visible in the render. In the Outliner, an *Eye Icon* means the object is visible in the viewport (and rendered preview), but the *Camera Icon* means if the object is visible in the actual render.

[image: outliner view]

**Only Rendering 1 Frame:**
For a render longer than 1 frame, make sure your start and end are as long as you want them to be in the Timeline.

[image: timeline view]

Comment: all the objects are visible in the render but i cant get the final result , i can get the final render in my laptop

Comment: You should definitely try to include screenshots of your scene, outliner, or something. And you said you cant get the final result but you can get the final render on your laptop?

Comment: i also cant get the final render as a picture or png

Comment: You can just Print Screen and upload it @Adam. If you can’t get a render at all you should try appending items to a new blender file.